# php variable with site wide scope

Tags: php, variables, global-variables, scope, kirby

I'm using [Kirby CMS](http://getkirby.com) and creating a little snippet which limits by posts by what number they are, and what date they are. A way to create a 'autopost' system basically.

```
$today = new DateTime("now"); //Declare today
$startdate = new DateTime("2013-09-12"); //Declare startdate
$interval = $startdate->diff($today); //Find the difference between startdate & today
$latest = $interval->format('%a'); //Declare $latest variable to be that interval, formatted as integer
```

So I have that little bit which creates my `$latest` variable which I can then use to control the posts that are displayed.

My problem is, I don't want to have to change my `$startdate` on every different kind of page template I have, so I want to make it site-wide somehow.

I tried putting it as a snippet with Kirby's `snippet()` function but that doesn't work. The snippets must be being brought into the page after the snippet has already been run I guess.

How can I make my snippet apply to my whole site?

Comment: You can try putting it in your file system. Write a code that writes startdate to a file and fetch it whenever you need from that file. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesn't have site-wide variables. The best you can do is put the assignments in a script, e.g. `site.php`, and have all your pages begin with `require 'site.php';` to initialize these variables.